# .htaccess redirect sub-directory to root issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My main domain is tied to my public_html folder but I use an .htaccess redirect to change the root directory to a sub-directory in the folder to make it easier to host multiple sites. Example:

```
public_html
-- .htaccess
-- site1
---- .htaccess
-- site2
-- site3
```

The .htaccess file in the root directory is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/ [L]
```

This works fine, but I think there are issues with this and the .htaccess file in my site1 directory. If I enter the URL it sometimes redirects to example.com/site1. So the website appears exactly the same on example.com and example.com/site1 but I don't want it to appear as example.com/site1. The second .htaccess file inside the site1 directory is show below.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Change default directory page
DirectoryIndex /home/

# Remove .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# Ensure all directory URLs have a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Same for HTTPS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect default error page to home page
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(/|error/)?$ /home/ [R=301,L]

# Error Documents
ErrorDocument 400 /error/?e=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error/?e=401
ErrorDocument 403 /error/?e=403
ErrorDocument 404 /error/?e=404
ErrorDocument 500 /error/?e=500

# Prevent viewing of htaccess file
<Files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue with the various rewrite rules I'm using that affects the URL, but I would appreciate any help if it can be resolved.

Thanks in advance and I apologise if my description isn't great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
# Ensure all directory URLs have a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [QSA,L,R=301]

# Same for HTTPS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/[^\/]*\.[^\/]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

It works for me. %{REQUEST_URI} contains site1, so don't use it.
QSA adds any URL parameters like ?param1=val1&param2=val2 If you don't use them, you may omit QSA.
Also while testing replace R=301 to R=302 (temporary redirect), else your browser remembers the rule and doesn't send request again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! With your changes enabled, if I visit the URL example.com/home and purposefully omit the trailing slash, instead of redirecting to include the trailing slash the site fails to load due to too many redirects! It may have been helpful to add I have a sub-directory inside the site1 folder for website assets with an .htaccess file containing:
`Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Disallow directory access
IndexIgnore *` and the issue mostly appears when omitting the trailing slash to the assets folder.

Comment: Sorry, added trailing slash in first block.

Comment: Thanks Vasiliy, that works for the pages in the main directory! However, a I said above I have an assets sub-directory with an .htaccess file blocking access. If I navigate to example.com/assets/ it works fine, but if I omit the trailing slash it redirects to example.com/site1/assets/. How can this be resolved?